# show echo notification at certain point

Tags: php, html, notifications

I'm new, so please be patient with me. ;) I want to show a little notification directly above my login form, and I have written a small function for this:

```
function message($text, $type)
{
    switch($type)
    {
    case "normal": 
      echo '<div class="alert alert-info fade in">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <i class="icon-info"></i> ' . $text . '
            </div>'; break;
```

... and so on. However, wherever I place this code with `<?php ?>` within the HTML code, it is always being shown on top of the page; so not directly over my login form thing. Why? Even though, I set this to the bottom, always on top - even above the header. I hope it became clear.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA8Nn.png <-- picture. Can't post it yet due to less reputation.

Comment: The login page work on client then no server code is executed ... you should use javascript for this (alia client side code)

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue.

Comment: Would also be helpful to see the full page that you are using it on.

Comment: Maybe it depends on some HTML error in the resulting page. I think the best way to debug is to look at its code in your browser (so you can already see the effect of **php** scripts)

Answer (score 0):

@Joe: right click your 'notification' element, view source. The reason it is displayed in that location is due to styling (CSS). Play around with the elements DOM properties to get it correct. Then apply the new properties to the HTML elements in your echo statement.

Comment: I'm new to this and I'm afraid that I don't have any plan.

Comment: Grab a piece of paper and a pencil, draw out what you envision the UI looking like; then put your hands on a keyboard. The more planning you do, the less headache you'll have.